# Hosting a ember application under angular Progressive web apps

Tags: ember.js, angular6, progressive-web-apps

We need to create a PWA with angular which will wrap the ember application and communicate through some navigation and events.

PWa will be just as a container which hosts the ember so that the application can be used as native and as webapps through every devices.

We need some approaches to get some solution regarding the above requirement.

Will it be possible for everyone to give some light one that.

Planning to host the application using iframe under PWA and communicate.Not sure whether it will be helpful or not.

Comment: You have to show the code you have so far and explain the specific problem you are getting. Otherwise the question can be closed as too broad.

Comment: why use both angular and ember? you can create a PWA with ember

Comment: I tried to answer your question but my answer is being deleted for being too broad. Reach out to me on twitter and I'll walk you through your issue

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best idea to use Angular to create a PWA for an Ember app, you should be doing this in Ember.

One reason that it might not be the greatest idea is that if you're adding Angular to your setup you are adding a minimum of 130KB of compressed JS before taking into account any features that you might be using. Assuming a baseline Ember app size you're talking about adding a roughly 60% extra JS to achieve something that can also be achieved by Ember.

It sounds like you might be following a tutorial on how to turn an app into a PWA that is based on Angular. If you are you having specific issues that you don't know how to solve with Ember I would recommend joining the [Ember Community Discord](https://emberjs.com/community/) and asking for some help there and maybe someone will point you in the right direction.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23616141)

Comment: I undeleted as this seems like helpful information for the question asker that may turn into an answer for them.

Comment: To be clear, @RadosławCybulski, I don't think what you did was incorrect. I think that it's not clear if this should be a comment or an answer as it's information that's valuable to the asker but not directly an answer to his question. Not what answers or comments are for, but still valuable. Grey area.